# How do I add items to multiple lists inside a loop?

Tags: python, list, loops

I am trying to add items to 9 lists that are already in 9 other lists.  I would like to have the first element of every list in the first list. And then the second element of each list into a second list.

So for example, I want my first output list using the three lists [1,2,3] and [3,2,1] to be [1,3].  I've come up with this but it keeps returning a KeyError:

```
def sudokuSolver():
    row1,row2,row3,row4,row5,row6,row7,row8,row9=([] for i in range(9))
    for k in range(1,10):
        for l in range(9):
           globals()['row%s' % k].append(globals()['cell%s' % k][l])
```

Comment: Work on your question. Makes no sense.

Comment: Start with: `puzzle = [[''] * 9 for i in range(9)]`.  Also, if you think you need to use `globals()` you are almost certainly wrong.

Comment: Try reading it another time it probably doesn't make sense but I'm not sure how else to explain it. Do you know why that particular code is returning a KeyError? I'm new to python so if you could give me an explanation that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example code makes little sense. But your question does. Therefore, I will answer your question.

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) is a convenient built-in function which iterates simultaneously through items of multiple iterables.

This is one application:

```
lst = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]

list(zip(*lst))[0]

# (1, 4, 7, 10)
```

Notice the unpacking operator `*`, the fact we need to wrap in `list` since `zip` is an interator, and indexer `[0]` which extracts the first element of each list.